# Keeping bootable images of all my operating systems and run them over LAN

Tags: images, operating-systems, remote

I love being able to run what ever, whenever.

Is is possible to store images of all my operating systems on a server, and run them over a LAN whenever I need to, on what ever computer I log in from?

I would love to imagine this would work kind of how I think cloud computing works, in that you can spool up a computer image whenever you need it and get it running.

All shared documents would be kept on another server, and I understand I wouldn't be able to share programs between images either, each would need their own install.

Just wondering what kind of flex I have.

Comment: Its possible to load system images through a private network.  What is your actual question?  If your asking if its possible to boot an operating system based off an image on a remote location....that isn't possible currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be possible to do a physical to virtual conversion of a running system and then you could mount it using a Hypervisor such as VMWare ESX/VSphere or Microsoft's Hyper-V.  You would then simply start the OS you wanted and connect using a tool such as RDP or VNC.  You could also create clean images from original media and then start fresh if converting is not an option

Desktop options such as Vmware Player or Workstation could work as well.

Shared storage could be accessed as long as the OS and the storage support that.

As you note, programs would need to be installed in each virtual machine

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of would be running VMware Workstation on your client side, and loading up VMs stored on your server. It's not what you're looking for *exactly*, but would still allow you a way of choosing an OS image to run, which was stored on another server. I would only attempt this if I was running GB LAN though, not 100Mbps!